# Remote Desktop visual GUI between two remote Linux computers?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, linux-mint

All the answers I've read seem to relate to connecting Linux to Windows or Windows to Linux or Linux to Linux just using a terminal.

I want to remotely connect to my Dads Linux Mint machine who lives the other side of the country from my Linux Mint machine using a visual display like what I have on my machine. So, Linux to Linux visually.

Both systems go via a Broadband router.

So, can anyone suggest how I achieve a GUI based visual display between the two Linux machines? Like you can do using Remote Desktop on two Windows computers?

Answer (score 6):

You can use VNC with a GUI application (via SSH tunnelling):

- [Setting up VNC on Mint](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1188)
- [Using Remmina with VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145537/how-to-configure-remmina-for-vnc-desktop-sharing)

If you're looking for a Windows-like multi-user remote desktop experience, you can use NX over SSH:

- [Installing FreeNX on Ubuntu (also applies to Mint)](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2012/05/how-to-install-freenx-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

Comment: nx does also seem to be significantly faster than X forwarding. It also lets you keep persistant sessions, which is awesome

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options I can think of. Chrome web browser has a desktop sharing app which will allow you to access remote computers easily. The other one is Teamviewer.

I have used both and can recommend them. They both work Linux to linux and also across platform.

[Chrome Remote desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en)

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)